# Anderer Ausdruck für "Ernährungseinschränkungen"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

Ich suche eine sinngemäße Übersetzung des englischen "dietary restrictions" für eine Abfrage der Teilnehmer einer Tagung. Hier sollen Teilnehmer angeben können, ob sie wegen Allergien, Unverträglichkeiten, religiöser Vorschriften oder eigener Entscheidungen (z.B. vegetarische Lebensweise) auf bestimmte Nahrung verzichten müssen.

Im leo Forum [1] gibt es dazu den Vorschlag "Ernährungseinschränkungen", was mir etwas gestelzt vorkommt, was aber anscheinend durchaus benutzt wird (siehe z.B. Google [2]).
Google translate [3] schlägt "diätetische Einschränkungen" vor, das klingt für mich nicht wirklich richtig.

Ist der beste, konzise Ausdruck, den ich hier verwenden kann, tatsächlich "Ernährungseinschränkungen"?

1. https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=861877&idForum=2&lang=en&lp=ende
2. https://www.google.com/search?q=Ern%C3%A4hrungseinschr%C3%A4nkungen
3. https://translate.google.com/#en/de/dietary%20restrictions

Comment: dietary restrictions klingt doch genauso gestelzt, finde ich

Comment: Es kommt doch sehr darauf an, in welchem Kontext du das Wort gebrauchen willst. Wissenschaftlicher Aufsatz? Infoblatt für Eltern im Kindergarten? Speisekarte eines Restaurants? Je nach Kontext (Textgattung, Zielpublikum) würde die Wortwahl anders ausfallen.

Comment: PS - Ein sehr gebräuchlicher Ausdruck (in bürokratischeren Textumgebungen) ist *Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit*. Es kommt aber - wie gesagt - sehr auf den Kontext an, ob das nun passt oder nicht. - Leute, die gegen demonstrativ zur Schau gestellte Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeiten von Leuten allergisch sind, leiden übrigens unter *Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeitsintoleranz*.

Comment: Wie beschrieben geht es um eine Tagung; "Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit" ist dabei zu eng gefasst, da das ja z.B. religiöse oder Lebenswandelgründe nicht mit einschließt. Aber ein Upvote für "Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeitsintoleranz" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da es um das Erfragen von Speisewünschen bzw. Ernährungsbesonderheiten von Konferenzgästen geht, und da dieses Abfragen wohl über ein Formular geschehen wird: Muss es wirklich eine Ein-Wort-Lösung sein?

Hier sind ein paar Ausdrücke, wie ich sie für so ein Formular in Erwägung ziehen würde:

> Besondere Anforderungen an Speisen:
>
> Kost-Besonderheiten:
>
> Einschränkungen bei Speisen:
>
> Besondere Speise-Regeln:
>
> Einschränkungen bei der Kost:
>
> Beschränkungen bei Lebensmitteln:

Dies sind alles nicht sehr häufige Ausdrücke, aber für deinen besonderen Fall passen sie gut. Alle bemühen sich um höfliche Neutralität, so dass Leute jeglicher Motivation sich angesprochen fühlen können.

Die Ausdrücke sind eher lang; aber *Ernährungseinschränkungen* wäre ja auch sehr lang. Und anders als *Ernährungseinschränkungen* sind die Ausdrücke wenigstens in "normalem", nicht bürokratieüberladenem Deutsch gehalten und wirken damit freundlicher.

Wenn du witzig oder sarkastisch sein willst, kannst du natürlich auch schreiben:

> Mein Fimmel beim Essen:

Das ist weniger neutral, aber es ist sehr gutes, idiomatisches Deutsch.

Comment: Mich wundert ja, dass das offiziöse "Diätvorschriften" nicht erwähnt wird. Und als Kompromiss vielleicht die "Ernährungsbesonderheiten" oder -eigenheiten.

Comment: _Mein Fimmel beim Essen_ finde ich grundsätzlich hervorragend, würde ich aber nicht (wie vom OP gewünscht)  an Tagungsteilnehmer richten. Das dürfte eher was für private Party-Einladungen sein.

Comment: Das widerspricht jetzt natürlich dem Tag single-word-request, aber du hast natürlich Recht, das muss gar nicht ein Wort sein; keine Ahnung warum ich da so festgefahren war. "Besondere Anforderungen an Speisen" gefällt mir sehr gut, danke.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht ob das regional bedingt ist, aber "Speise" klingt bei mir so archaisch und/oder gehoben, dass es nicht als geeignete allgemeine Wortwahl für "Essen" oder "Lebensmittel" durchgehen kann.

Comment: @jarnbjo   Du hast vollkommen recht, daß *Speise* altmodisch beziehungsweise gehobene Sprachverwendung ist. Aber das Gehobene wäre ja angemessen hier, da es um eine Konferenzeinladung geht. Von alltagssprachlichen Redeweisen wie *Essen* würde ich hier Abstand halten.

Comment: @LangLangC   Für mein Empfinden klingt *Diätvorschriften* zu stark nach einer medizinischen Indikation. Der Fragesteller sucht aber einen möglichst neutralen Ausdruck, der es vollkommen offen lässt, wo die Motivation für die Beschränkung der Nahrungsmittelauswahl herkommt.

Comment: [Diätvorschriften](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/diätvorschriften.html) klingt [nicht unbedingt](http://context.reverso.net/übersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Diätvorschriften) nach medizin. Vor allem, wenn man den "Fimmel" so dreht: "Diätvorschriften, die wir für Sie einhalten sollten"

Comment: Bei Diät im Deutschen ist doch die erste Assoziation eigentlich "Abnehmen" und die zweite "ärztlicher Rat". Eine Einschränkung des Speiseplans aufgrund religiöser Vorschriften (kein Schwein), weltanschaulicher Entscheidung (vegan) oder "schmeckt mir nicht" wird davon nicht erfasst. Die Bedeutung des englischen "diet" ist da IMHO weiter gefasst und keine 1:1-Übersetzung des deutschen "Diät".

Answer (score 10):

Das ist üblicherweise auch ein Problem von Fluggesellschaften, die ihren Gästen was zu essen anbieten. Die [Lufthansa](https://www.lufthansa.com/de/de/Sondermahlzeiten) formuliert das so:

> Fluggäste, die aus diätischen, religiösen oder ernährungsphysiologischen Gründen spezielle Kost zu sich nehmen, können auf von Lufthansa durchgeführten Flügen zwischen 14 verschiedenen Mahlzeiten wählen.

Die wörtliche Übersetzung von *dietary restrictions* in "Ernährungseinschränkungen" klingt auf Deutsch wesentlich negativer als im Englischen. "spezielle Kost" ist wesentlich neutraler.

Die [Austrian](https://www.austrian.com/Info/Flightinformation/Special%20Meals.aspx?sc_lang=de&cc=DE) formuliert noch neutraler und spricht von einem *besonderen Essenswunsch.*

Die [Swiss](https://www.swiss.com/ch/de/fliegen/an-bord/verpflegung/spezialmenues.html) spricht von *Fluggästen mit aussergewöhnlichen Anforderungen* und bietet ihnen ein "besonderes Menü" an. Finde ich eher nicht so glücklich.

Comment: +1 für "besonderen Essenswunsch"

Comment: Warum sollen denn die *restrictions* positiver klingen als Einschränkungen? Ohne Beleg und frei nach Ohr möchte ich dem einfach widersprechen. "Special food" (oder was LH dann nimmt) klingt wiederum nach Sonderschule, mäkelig etc. Bei Essen und Diät kommen Geschmack und Medizin und Spinnereien zusammen: also Religion, Veganismus, Gesundheit, Allergien, Unverträglichkeiten, komische Kulturen etc.  Wenn das keine Einschränkungen sind––mindestens die Köche werden da zustimmen.

Comment: @LangLangC *Religion ist eine Einschränkung*??? Und was bitte sind "komische Kulturen"?

Comment: Das hab ich nicht geschrieben, stimme dem aber zu. *re-ligare* Als Jude auf Schinken, als Moslem auf Alkohol *zu verzichten* ist eine Einschränkung. – Komische Kulturen sind zB Glutengläubige, die sonst relative gesund sind, Makrobiotiker etc. Solche, die sich das Motto "Du bist was Du nicht isst" mit Distinktionskonsum verbinden. Auf höherer Ebene auch Ernährungsberater, Orthorektiker und sogenannte Gourmets… Allgemein ist der Mensch ein Omnivore und gedeiht bei Mischost prächtig. Krankheiten ausgenommen: der größte Teil aller DIäten ist Schmonzes, Geschmack ist gelernt. Das ist sehr komisch.

Comment: Auch +1 für "besondere Essenswünsche". Das ist doch eine relativ weit verbreitete Bezeichnung, die ich so oft schon gesehen habe, klingt wertneutral und deckt offensichtlich sowohl Allergien, religiöse Einschränkungen und auch reine Vorlieben ab.

Answer (score 5):

Statt »Ernährungseinschränkungen« könnte man neutral bzw. beschönigend

> Ernährungspräferenzen

sagen.

*Beispiel*

> - Glutenfreies Brot
> - Kein Schweinefleisch
> - Kein Alkohol in der Minibar / Nur Fassbier

Comment: Allergien sind aber keine Präferenzen! Ich hab damit schon schlechte Erfahrungen gemacht, weil sobald es nur eine "Präferenz" ist, nehmen es manche Restaurants nicht mehr ganz so genau mit der Zutatenliste.

Comment: "nur Fassbier" ist natürlich eine sehr spezielle *Ernährungseinschränkung*. +1, weil ich meinen Spass damit habe. Der arme Kerl!

Comment: @tofro: Nichts zu machen, manche habens schwer, das arme Schwein darf nur Fassbier trinken.

Answer (score 0):

Ich sehe nicht ein, warum schon der Begriff die Verneinung (also die Beschränkung) enthalten muss:

> Diätrichtlinien

würde

*kalorienarm*, *alkoholfrei*, *vegetarisch*, oder einfach *keine* als Antwort erlauben.

Die zwingende Vermeidung eines Stoffes (wegen der Gefahr eines allergischen Schocks) ist damit zwar noch nicht abgedeckt, das sehe ich aber auch bei den anderen vorgeschlagenen Begriffen nicht.